# Using .getName to print a File name

Tags: java

So I'm just unsure as how to use this method. I have a program that prints the count for Word, character and line but I would also like it to say the filename before it spits out this information. I have looked at info on this but I am unsure as how to implement this with my program.

```
package practicefiles;

import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PracticeFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int charCount = 0;
        int wordCount = 0;
        int lineCount = 0;
        String count;
        StringTokenizer st;
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter file: ");
        count = buf.readLine();
        buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(count));
        while ((count = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            lineCount++;
            st = new StringTokenizer(count, " ,;:.");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                wordCount++;
                count = st.nextToken();
                charCount += count.length();
            }
        }
        // String fileName = count.getName();
        System.out.println("Character Count : " + charCount);
        System.out.println("Word Count : " + wordCount);
        System.out.println("Line Count : " + lineCount);
        buf.close();
    }
}
```

So Summary: Ask for file, user inputs file, prints out char, word and line count. Would like to print out filename before this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to create a string from your buf.readLine() line and then create a new file that you would pass to the FileReader using your string from before. You can then reference the file later using getName();

```
public class PracticeFiles {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
int charCount=0;
int wordCount=0;
int lineCount=0;
String count;
StringTokenizer st;
BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter file: ");
    String fileName = buf.readLine();
    File file = new File(fileName);
    buf=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while((count=buf.readLine())!=null)
        {
            lineCount++;
            st=new StringTokenizer(count," ,;:.");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    wordCount++;
                    count=st.nextToken();
                    charCount+=count.length();
                }
        }
        System.out.println("The file name is: " + file.getName());
        System.out.println("Character Count : " + charCount);
        System.out.println("Word Count : " + wordCount);
        System.out.println("Line Count : " + lineCount);
        buf.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `count.getName();` because count is a `String` not a `File`.

When you make your `BufferedReader`, you supply it a `FileReader`, and when you're making that `FileReader` you're giving it the path to the file you're opening.

If you want to refer to that `File` later, then you need to make a variable that stores it.

`File inputFile = new File(count);`

then when you make your `BufferedReader` you could use would use
`buf=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));`

and when you want to get the name of the `File` you would use `inputFile.getName();`

Comment: No one should be using java.io.File anymore.  [Paths.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) and [Files.newBufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of this change.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
package practicefiles;

import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PracticeFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int charCount = 0;
        int wordCount = 0;
        int lineCount = 0;
        File file;
        String count;
        StringTokenizer st;
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter file: ");
        file = new File(buf.readLine()); // <-- this is new
        System.out.println("Use "+file.getAbsolutePath());
        buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((count = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            lineCount++;
            st = new StringTokenizer(count, " ,;:.");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                wordCount++;
                count = st.nextToken();
                charCount += count.length();
            }
        }
        // String fileName = count.getName();
        System.out.println("Character Count : " + charCount);
        System.out.println("Word Count : " + wordCount);
        System.out.println("Line Count : " + lineCount);
        buf.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: A large block of code with no explanation of what you changed, or why, is not an especially useful answer.